# Listening to JSplitPane divider location changes by user only?

Tags: java, swing, jsplitpane, propertychangelistener

I am trying to implement a JSplitPane that saves its state to some configuration file, so i added a listener like this one :

```
mHorSplitPane.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent changeEvent) {
                JSplitPane sourceSplitPane = (JSplitPane) changeEvent.getSource();
                String propertyName = changeEvent.getPropertyName();
                if (propertyName.equals(JSplitPane.DIVIDER_LOCATION_PROPERTY)) {
                    mController.writeSplitPaneProperty((int) (sourceSplitPane.getDividerLocation()/(float)sourceSplitPane.getBounds().width*100));

                }
            }
        });
```

which handles it just fine, but for some reason sometimes Swing code itself changes this property and  changes the divider location, any suggestion on how can i overcome this?

Comment: `but for some reason sometimes Swing code itself changes this property` ---> there are three possibilities `1.` your code together with used LayoutManager `2.` your code & methods implemented in JSplitPane API,  `3.` used LayoutManager & methods implemented in JSplitPane API

Comment: are you offering a way to determine if the invokation of the method is by program or by user?

Comment: `but for some reason sometimes Swing code itself changes this property --->` - I am not aware of why Swing would do this. Post your SSCCE that demonstrates the problem. If you resize the frame and the splitpane changes in size then I can see this value changing but this makes sense to me. Maybe you should be handling the windowClosing() event to save the state of your components.